# Why wont this code work to create a new in worksheeet with data entry

Tags: excel, vba

Although very new to VBA I have written the following but i'm lost as creating new sheet is ok and copy a data range but together things go wrong and nothing happens ?

Any help gratefully received.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sheet.Name <> "Project Evaluation Tool" And Sheet.Name <> "fx" And Sheet.Name <> "Needs" Then
            Sheet.Range("D12:L18").Copy
            Sheet.Range("Q12:Y18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub Wsh_PasteSpecial()
Dim WshSrc As Worksheet
Dim WshTrg As Worksheet

Rem Set working worksheets
Set WshSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
Set WshTrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Target")

    WshSrc.Cells.Copy
    With WshTrg.Cells
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do:

Stage 1 - Press button to copy/capture a range of information form one sheet

Stage 2 - Create a new sheet (Blank) from a Master Template

Stage 3 - Paste Stage 1 data into appropriate cells in Stage 2

Stage 4 - Add name to Tab

Stage 6 - User adds data normally to complete Template

Stage 7 - Enable Template to be saved and to print a PDF.

Stage 8 - Repeat but do not overwrite previous but create new etc

Help ??

Comment: There's nothing in your code to create a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

As @SJR pointed out, you're creating a worksheet object but there isn't an actual worksheet being created. Insert the following into your code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Target"
```